# Doctrine2 YAML schema - how to define primary key in centre of schema?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, yaml

I am importing a remote CSV daily into MySQL using Doctrine.  The remote CSV has the primary key in the **centre** of the schema rather than at the beginning or end.

This seems to make it impossible to assign this 'id' as the primary key using doctrine.  I have to preserve this primary key for matching purposes.

```
    UKtradestransaction:
      type: entity
      repositoryClass: UktradesTransactionRepository
      table: uktrades_transactions
      fields:
        owner_id:
          type: integer
          length: 9
          nullable: true
        security_id:
          type: integer
          length: 9
        id:   # THIS NEEDS TO BE THE PRIMARY KEY
          type: integer
          length: 12
        exercise_price_uk:
          type: decimal
          length: 15
          scale: 4
          nullable: true
        update_date:
          type: date
          nullable: true
      id:
        id:  # THIS WILL NOT WORK 
          type: integer
          length: 12
          generator:
              strategy:auto
```

The above will not work as the final id field duplicates the id in the centre.

How do I assign the middle 'id' field as the primary key?  Is there not a way to define the 'id' field as the primary key inline in the 'fields' definition?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the order of the fields is important. The Doctrine allow to determine the primary key in the fields or [before them](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#identifiers-primary-keys), a syntax I personally prefer. Simply remove the `id` from the list of fields, it will be still considered as a field.